# allow user to add jbutton dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am using jFrame and in my jFrame there is three text field and jButton the textField is for Item number and item name and item price when a jButton is pressed the will create a JButtin in other jFrame that jButton connected to database to add the price and item name to the jTable how i can do that

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem? Where are you stuck and why?

Comment: i know how to create swing by code but my question is how i can allow user to do that by just press jbutton

Comment: It will still be "by code". Only you need to execute such code in response to an user action. Do you know about Event Listeners?

Comment: @mohza: see edit to answer. You're really going to have to improve this question quite a bit if we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: i am new to java i know just little bit since i start study java before 3 month

Comment: Fine. Then work through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) first.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help but wonder if yours isn't an XY Problem type question, but you would create a JButton as you would most any other object,...

```
 JButton myButton = new JButton(someTextOrActionHere);
```

And then adding it to a container is easy:

```
someJPanel.add(myButton);
someJPanel.revalidate(); // to have the layout managers layout the button
someJPanel.repaint();   // often needed to clean up dirty pixels.
```

But this is trivial stuff, and I have a feeling that your problem lies in questions that you've not yet told us. Please consider improving your question a bit.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> i know how to create swing by code but my question is how i can allow user to do that by just press jbutton

That's just it, there is no magic to this. You use the same code as above, except it is instigated by a button's ActionListener. Again, if you need more help, you're going to have to put a lot more into your question, including code and detail. It will take work on your part, but it will be well worth it.

Comment: what am trying to do is that i want to create cashier program in this program the will be 2 jFrame one is  additem and other one is mainframe that contain item . what i want is when the user add item in

Comment: @mohza, again, show pertinent code, show us what you've tried, tell us how it's not working, ... As an aside, it is rare for an application to have two JFrames. If it needs to show two windows one is usually a JDialog.